# Automatic creation of polygons from Feature Class points in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, topology

I have two point feature classes, let's call them `A` and `B`. They are well-spaced and the points are non-overlapping:

[image: Points of two types]

My objective is to create a topology using these two sets of points by connecting the minimum number of `A` points together to form polygons each of which contains one `B` point. The result would look something like this:

[image]

I am familiar with how to use the [Topology rules](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/01mm/pdf/topology_rules_poster.pdf) within a [Feature Dataset](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=An_overview_of_working_with_feature_datasets) to ensure that the polygons do not overlap and that the `A` points appear on the edges of the polygons, whereas the `B` points are properly contained.

I am not familiar with any way to automatically calculate/draw the edges of the polygons themselves in ArcGIS. Is there a tool (or sequence of tools) I could use to automatically group the `A` feature class points into the vertices of polygons and then produce an output feature class of polygons?

If not, then the solution I'll have to pursue will be to write a toolbox script to process the `A` and `B` feature classes and generate a new polygon output class. If there is a "quick" way to do this, without having to write my own Python interacting with `arcPy`, I'd love to know.

Comment: something like a TIN from A containing B? I don't know of any tool that will do that per se but you could start with a TIN, convert the edges to polygons and then select the ones that don't contain B points and remove using Eliminate with longest side option iteratively until all polygons contain a B point.

Comment: My first thought is creating a TIN too, and the other one is to think about Thiessen polygons.

Comment: Impossible to suggest anyting, because I don't know how to reproduce 'well placed points'. Are you able to share subsets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Triangulate points A:

[image]

Create Thiessen proximity polygons for points B:

[image]

Intersect 2 layers. Add field area and populate it by polygons’ area. Sort table in descending order using area field.
From sorted table remove duplicate (not first) records using field Tri_Index:

[image]

Join above table to triangles using Tri_Index for joining. Use field B_ID (points B id field) to show triangles:

[image]

I hope the rest is obvious and I also want to hope that pattern of points relative to each other is similar for the rest of study area